# Restricting forged access to remote PHP page which is usually accessed through AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, drupal

I'm building a Drupal site that has a little voting system. I have a PHP page which takes in parameters and updates the voting database accordingly. How do I allow this page to be accessed through this AJAX on my Drupal site but otherwise restrict access to outside users just going to this URL to prevent forged voting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AJAX == regular HTTP request. You cannot distinguish an AJAX request from a "normal access". There is no way to prevent this.

To prevent wrong votes, you need to build such security into your voting system. Require registration, use sessions and nonces or whatever is necessary. But trying to "block non-AJAX requests" is not a solution.

Comment: I see. Well with each request it deletes all previous votes under that user id so there can only be one per user id. Now I just need to confirm server side that the user id given matches up with the currently logged in Drupal user. I'm having trouble getting this information on this external PHP script though. Seems I can only access those variables in some kind of actual Drupal page.

Comment: Why don't you move the voting system to drupal ?

Comment: That is what I am trying. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Worked out well, thanks! I think everything is pretty secure now.

Answer (score 2):

You can rely on `'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'` HTTP header that is appended to each Ajax request by most standard browsers.

Yet, as @deceze pointed out, it's far from being considered 'secure'. It's quite easy to issue 'normal' http request that include this header, either by using Fiddler or programatically.

If you just need to restrict voting by simple refresh of the browser address bar, just change the script to get the vote value using http `POST` verb.